# syntax error : missing ';' before ')'

Tags: visual-c++

I have a nested loop and am getting this error, however as far as i know i DONT need another ';' in this section of code

```
    while ( inFile >> location >> elevation >> precipAmount )
{

    for (count, count <= 12, count ++)
```

I am getting the error after the last close parentheses.

Comment: Try one of the multitude of online resources dedicated to learning visual C++ before asking on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Your `for` loop has syntax errors, note the semi colons instead of commars:

```
for (count; count <= 12; count ++)
```

Answer (score 2):

`for` loops use `;` to seperate the parts. It should be

```
for (count; count <= 12; count++)
```

Also the first part is used to initalise anything before the loop starts. You should either set `count` to a value or remove it as it is currently doing nothing

```
for (; count <= 12; count++)
// or
for (count = 0; count <= 12; count++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
for (count; count <= 12; count ++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Write `for (count; count <= 12; count ++)`